# how to use the values obtained from onmeasure in a separate thread

Tags: android

i am using this omeasure method to find the width of the vew and it is returning the correct values.

```
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {


        parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        parentheight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        this.setMeasuredDimension(
                parentWidth, parentheight);
        //Log.d("Measure", "width = " + parentWidth + ", height = " 
                //+ this.getMeasuredHeight());
    }
```

now i want to use the value parentWidth in the following if statement

```
public void run()
{
    a.flag2=true;
    while(a.flag2)
    {   
        try
        {
            sleep(200);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        }

    if(!a.flag1)
    {
        a.leftx+=10;
        a.rightx+=10;
        if(!a.flag3)
        {
            a.strt-=15;
            a.arc+=15;
        }   
        else
        {
            a.strt+=15;
            a.arc-=15;
        }

    }

    if(a.flag1)
    {
        a.leftx-=10;
        a.rightx-=10;
        if(!a.flag3)
            a.arc+=15;
        if(a.flag3)
            a.arc-=15;
    }   

    if(a.rightx==432)
    {

        a.topy+=60;
        a.bottomy+=60;
        a.flag1=true;
        a.strt=180;
        a.arc=315;  
    }

    if(a.leftx==0)
    {
        a.topy+=60;
        a.bottomy+=60;
        a.flag1=false;
        a.strt=45;
        a.arc=315;

    }
    if(a.bottomy>=660)
    {
        a.topy=60;
        a.bottomy=120;
    }

    if(a.strt==0 || a.arc==360)
    {
        a.flag3=true;
    }

    if(a.strt==45 || a.arc==315)
    {
        a.flag3=false;
    }
    if(a.n3==a.rightx&&a.n5==(a.topy+a.bottomy)/2)
    {
        a.i+=1;
        int low=1;
        int high=10;

        a.n=a.r.nextInt(high-low);
        a.n3=(a.n*10)+150;
        a.n5=(a.n*60)+90;

        a.f1=(float)a.n3;
        a.f2=(float)a.n5;



    }
    a.postInvalidate();
    }
}
}
```

this if statement is defined inside a thread class.but somehow the value of parentWidth is not being read her.if i harcode it like "a.rightx==432" then it works.but i dont want to hardcode it. how should i get the value of parentWidth in this thread?

Comment: It sounds as though onMeasure might trigger after your thread.  However, typically if you want to get a value to pass into a thread you would store the value/object as a final variable before launching the thread as per thread safety rules.

Comment: can you add more code of how your thread interacts with the view?

Comment: @user1873880 i have added the thread class

Comment: @user1873880 i have added the thread class

Comment: @JaySnayder sir the onmeasure triggers before the threa as these values reach the constructor of the thread.